# SCSS : Mixin & multiple lists issue

Tags: list, sass, mixins

I try to learn scss list with mixins.

I wrote a simple mixin which add a background-url regarding the variables in a list.

It's written in a *_mixins.scss* file :

```
 $path: "../images/";

 @mixin dynamic-bg($path, $type, $ext) {
   @each $source in $source-list {
     &[data-bg="#{$source}"] {
         background: url($path + $source + '_' + $type + '.' + $ext) no-repeat;
     }
   }
 }
```

I call it in another file, and "describe" the list content just before :

```
 a {
    $source-list: "alpha", "beta", "gamma"

    @include dynamic-bg($path, "logo", "png");
 }
```

It should result in CSS like this :

```
 a[data-bg="alpha"] {
    background: url("../images/alpha_logo.png") no-repeat;
 }
 a[data-bg="beta"] {
    background: url("../images/beta_logo.png") no-repeat;
 }
 a[data-bg="gamma"] {
    background: url("../images/gamma_logo.png") no-repeat;
 }
```

**But I get this error :**
*Undefined variable: "$source-list"*

It works fine if I add the list content before the mixin in *_mixins.scss*, but if so I can't re-use it over and over just by modifying the list's content.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,

AW

Answer (score 1):

> It works fine if I add the list content before the mixin in _mixins.scss, but if so I can't re-use it over and over just by modifying the list's content.

When calling the mixin your list is out of scope, because you defined it within the `a { ... }` part. To make the list visible to your mixin you would have to define the list outside (not necessarily before the mixin, but at least before you call the mixin).

```
$path: "../images/";

@mixin dynamic-bg($path, $type, $ext) {
 @each $source in $source-list {
   &[data-bg="#{$source}"] {
       background: url($path + $source + '_' + $type + '.' + $ext) no-repeat;
   }
 }
}

$source-list: "alpha", "beta", "gamma";

a {
  @include dynamic-bg($path, "logo", "png");
}

$source-list: "new1", "new2";

strong {
 @include dynamic-bg($path, "logo", "png");
}
```

compiles to:

```
a[data-bg="alpha"] {
  background: url("../images/alpha_logo.png") no-repeat;
}
a[data-bg="beta"] {
  background: url("../images/beta_logo.png") no-repeat;
}
a[data-bg="gamma"] {
  background: url("../images/gamma_logo.png") no-repeat;
}

strong[data-bg="new1"] {
  background: url("../images/new1_logo.png") no-repeat;
}
strong[data-bg="new2"] {
  background: url("../images/new2_logo.png") no-repeat;
}
```

---

If you put the list inside of the `a` for the reason that no other definition should be able to make use of it, you'd better go for an additional (optional) mixin parameter:

```
@mixin dynamic-bg($path, $type, $ext, $sources: $source-list) {
 @each $source in $sources {
   &[data-bg="#{$source}"] {
       background: url($path + $source + '_' + $type + '.' + $ext) no-repeat;
   }
 }
}

$source-list: "default-1", "default-2";

a {
  $source-list: "alpha", "beta", "gamma";
  @include dynamic-bg($path, "logo", "png", $source-list);
}

strong {
  @include dynamic-bg($path, "logo", "png");
}
```

compiles to:

```
a[data-bg="alpha"] {
  background: url("../images/alpha_logo.png") no-repeat;
}
a[data-bg="beta"] {
  /* ... */

strong[data-bg="default-1"] {
  background: url("../images/default-1_logo.png") no-repeat;
}
strong[data-bg="default-2"] {
  /* ... */
```

or just like the following with a required parameter and no additional `$source-list` variable:

```
@mixin dynamic-bg($path, $type, $ext, $source-list) {
 @each $source in $source-list {
   &[data-bg="#{$source}"] {
       background: url($path + $source + '_' + $type + '.' + $ext) no-repeat;
   }
 }
}

a {
  @include dynamic-bg($path, "logo", "png", ("alpha", "beta", "gamma"));
}

strong {
  @include dynamic-bg($path, "logo", "png", ("strong-1", "strong-2"));
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that I would have to define the list outside where I call the mixin. It change everything :) 

I just rewrote my mixin (before I see your answer), I've finally used an **Arglist** (which I didn't know about before now). 

It looks a bit like what you did above : 

     $targets-list: "alpha", "beta", "gamma"; 
     @include dynamic-bg($path, "icon", "png", $targets-list...);

If I guess well, "$targets-list..." is best for *'unlimited' list* and "$targets-list" is for *'limited list'*?

Thank you for your answer, I really apreciate it !

Comment: [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-multiple-arguments-lists-or-arglist/) explains arglists pretty good :)

Comment: Yep, it's this one I've found!